# word build_grid not defined in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a grid where a player can move around. In my code it says that the word build_grid is not defined. Can someone help.
Thanks

```
if Menuinput == "1":
      grid = build_grid
      break

def grid_size():
        size = 8
        grid = []

def build_grid(size):
      x_axis = list(range(0,size))
      y_axis = list(range(0,size))
      grid_list = []

      for x_point in x_axis:
        for y_point in y_axis:
          grid_point = (x_point,y_point)
          grid_list.append(grid_point)

      return grid_list
```

Comment: `build_grid` is not yet defined when you try to use it on your second line. So, move that first part at the end of the code, after the definition of `build_grid`. Also, you want to call it and assign the returned value to grid, so it should be `grid  = build_grid()` with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace it in some IDE, step-by-step and to see that execution of top-level statements, for example, of `def` creates/defines defining function. So, top-level/module-level execution step over `if`, but `def` is not yet executed, so function was not defined actually. Python is dynamic and scripting language ;)